# Laravel - use two parameters in Route:bind

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I am new in Laravel Framework and I've got an ajax request with URL: `/translate/cs/abeceda`

The **route** for this link is:

```
Route::get('/translate/{lang}/{word}', 'DictionaryController@translate')->name('translateWord');
```

and the **Route::bind** is:

```
class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

   public function boot() {
    //some code

    Route::bind('word', function($word){
        dd(Route::currentRouteName());
        $language = Language::where('code', app()->getLocale())->first();
        if($language){
            if($word = Word::where('word', 'like', '%' . $word . '%')->where('language_id', $language->id)->first()){
                return $word;
            }
            throw new \Exception('Invalid word');
        }
        throw new \Exception('Invalid language');
    });

    parent::boot();
}
```

}

Instead of `app()->getLocale()` I need to get the URL **lang parameter** (in this case `cs`). Is there any possibility to get the lang param?

Comment: `request()->route('lang')` or `request()->route()->parameters()` if you want the array.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy How is that possible? I tried it once, but it gave me `null` :/